# CSS images and texts hovering both

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to apply an effect to my pics when I put the cursor over them. What I want is a greyscale filter and a that a text appears. I've used this code:

`HTML:`

```
<div class="upic_wrap">
    <img class="upic" src="foo.jpg"> 
    <div class="upic_text">Avenida Central</div>
</div>
```

`CSS:`

```
.upic_text {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
}
.upic:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); 
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.upic_wrap:hover .upic_text {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px yellow;
}
```

I get this:

[image: off pic](out of pic)

[image: hover pic](hover pic, yes! what I want!)

Which is perfect, but the problem is when the cursor is over the text. That's what happen: 
[image: error](hover text, noooo!)

I would like to always get the effect of "hover pic" (the second) when I hover the pic or the text.

How could I solve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the issues. The thing is to set `:hover` of the `.upic_wrap` selector.

This snippet is based on your initial code, but I think it needs some changes to look like the pictures you posted.

```css
.upic_text {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity:0;
}
.upic_wrap:hover .upic {
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); 
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.upic_wrap:hover .upic_text {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="upic_wrap">
    <img class="upic" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKgfx.png"> 
    <div class="upic_text">Avenida Central</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: You'r welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one, if it finally fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.upic_wrap
{
border: 1px solid red;
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.upic
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
.upic_text {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: none;
}
.upic_wrap:hover .upic {
    opacity:0.5;
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%); 
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.upic_wrap:hover .upic_text {
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
    color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="upic_wrap">
  <img class="upic" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png"> 
  <div class="upic_text">Avenida Central</div>
</div>
```

your query is convert in to fully responsive and solved to something changes in css.